# Manipulating Check Box Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

An HTML page that contains four checkboxes with the values Red, Green, Blue and Black is created here. Using jQuery functions you have to check whether the checkboxes are checked or not and also display a number of checkboxes checked. Use the  tag with the id "result" to display the message.

**Desired output:**
[image: Click this link to see desired output]

**Note:-** Do not alter the given 'chkbox.html' file. Write your jQuery code in the file 'chkbox.js'.
Avoid writing the jQuery 'document ready' method for the proper web page visibility.
chkbox.html file is given below:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Check Box using jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form">
     <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red"/>Red
     <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green"/>Green
     <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value="Blue"/>Blue
     <input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black"/>Black<br/>
  </form>
  <div id="result">0 boxes are checked</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="chkbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to write chkbox.js. Can somebody please help?
The code that I have written is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var $checkboxes= $('#form input[type="checkbox"]');
     $checkboxes.change(function(){
       var ccc= $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
       $('span').text(ccc);
     });
   });
```

Comment: Your code almost works. You're just trying to change the content of a span (`$('span')`) instead of your result div (`$('#result')`).

Comment: Please share more details. What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to make it work?

Comment: @metratron note that [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) questions *are* [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as long as they are valid questions and not just "do this for me".   This appears to be a valid question where OP has had a (pretty good) attempt, but has got stuck and needs a 2nd pair of eyes.

Comment: *Avoid writing the jQuery 'document ready' method for the proper web page visibility* - what does this even mean?  How does doc.ready affect "web page visibility?"  Your code, with the `<script src=chkbox.js` as the last line of the `body` means you don't *need* doc.ready, but there's no reason not to include it.

Comment: Code works fine with just change to `$("#result")` as suggested by @Reyno  https://jsfiddle.net/m73n5Lkw/

Answer (score 3):

The script code is trying to modify span tag, which doesn't exist in HTML, another thing the script code is unable to find that checkbox is checked or not.
you can try below solution.

```
  <form id="form">
     <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red"/>Red
     <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green"/>Green
     <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value="Blue"/>Blue
     <input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black"/>Black<br/>
 </form>
 <div id="result">0 boxes are checked</div>
```

**.is(":chekced")** can check, checkbox is checked or not

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $checkboxes= $('#form input[type="checkbox"]');
  var counter = 0;
  $checkboxes.change(function(){
     $(this).is(":checked") ? counter++ : counter--;
     $('#result').text(counter+"  boxes are checked");
   });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $checkboxes= $('#form input[type="checkbox"]');
  var counter = 0;
  $checkboxes.change(function(){
     $(this).is(":checked") ? counter++ : counter--;
     $('#result').text(counter + " boxes are checked");
   });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
 <form id="form">
     <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="red" value="Red"/>Red
     <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="green" value="Green"/>Green
     <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="blue" value="Blue"/>Blue
     <input type="checkbox" id="black" name="black" value="Black"/>Black<br/>
 </form>
 <div id="result">0 boxes are checked</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried using the code provided by you but still not working

Comment: can you share more details.. I have tried the code and edited the answer with running snippet. Please check the fiddle as well for working solution https://jsfiddle.net/rjxe9v0p/

Comment: @anshikagoel will you please mention still what *not working* ?

Comment: *the script code is unable to find that checkbox is checked* that's what the `.fitler(":checked").length` does - filters the checkboxes to just those that are ticked.  By counting them as they change (in this answer), you'll miss if any were checked to start with or changed via code, whereas counting them each time may be slower if there's 10,000+ but ensures an accurate result.

Comment: The code mentioned above works fine but I am unable to pass the test case. The test case says - Check for  - One check box is checked.